# pip not working Windows

Tags: python, pip

pip is not working on Windows its giving me an empty output using`pip install virtualenv` but when I try and use virtualenv i get virtualenv is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
[image]

I've added both C:[pythonroute]\Python35-32 and C:[pythonroute]\Python35-32\Scripts to my enviroment variables

the cmd command python works

[image]

Comment: `virtualenv` is not yet installed. Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes i"m connected to the internet. pip is just not installing the `virtualenv` and I don't understand why

Comment: what does `pip --version` say?

Comment: Empty response all pip elated command go empty like in the image

Comment: then there is something else in your computer hijacking the `pip` command. look for a pip.bat or pip.exe in system path that is not in python/lib/site-packages folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try use the following command if You can run python via cmd.

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating pip. You can do this by:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Make sure you run this as administrator.
Additionally check if virtualenv is installed via

```
pip list
```

Comment: I've tried both every command involving pip gives me an empty response like in the image

Answer (score 0):

On the main folder of your venv, there's a file called "pyvenv.cfg"

Open with notepad and it will be like:

```
home = c:\program files (x86)\python38-32
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.8.3.final.0
virtualenv = 20.0.21
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = c:\program files (x86)\python38-32
base-exec-prefix = c:\program files (x86)\python38-32
base-executable = c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe
```

Make sure to change this line:
include-system-site-packages = true

Also, make sure to give yourself Full Control of the venv folder. Right click on the folder, Proprieties, Security, Edit. Then select your User and enable full control.

After that, start your venv and pip should be working.